# Exportar datos a Excel usando php

Tags: php

tengo un pequeño problema en cuanto a exportar los datos , lo que utilizo es un rango de fechas que al seleccionar me trae la información adecuada ; lo que necesito es que me descargue un archivo en formato Excel. Actualmente descarga el archivo CSV lo que debo es cambiar dicha extensión.

```
include "conexion.php";
$filename = 'ventas.csv';


header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'");
header("Content-Disposition: filename=reporte_ventas.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

Esto es lo que utilizo para dicha operación , el código no presenta ningún error solo necesito cambiar la extensión y que me esporte bien el archivo Excel

Comment: ¿Tratas de decir que con ese código no te descarga un archivo excel?

Comment: @gaidyjg Si me descarga pero en un archivo plana csv , si no Excel

Comment: Supongo que de nombre _ventas.csv_, ¿cierto?

Comment: @gaidyjg si , es correcto.

Comment: Tus cabeceras están correctas, pero si te fijas, en el Content-disposition, tu filename es distinto al de tu variable filename. Los archivos csv no deberían darte problemas si solo le cambias la extensión, es decir, solo debes colocar _ventas.xls_ y debería abrirte como un archivo excel común y corriente.

Comment: @gaidyjg sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Prueba con: `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="reporte_ventas.xls"');`

Comment: No tendrás que cambiar el nombre de archivo para que tenga la extensión xls? `$filename = 'ventas.xls';`

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a reemplazar tus comas del csv por tabulaciones (`\t`). Luego, cambia la extensión del `$filename` por `.xls` y asegurate de que el nombre coincida con el del header.

Answer (score 0):

`````
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
* Función encargada de exportar a excel.
* Recibe como parametro un arreglo de datos.
*---------------------------------------------------------------*/

    function exportProductDatabase($productResult) {

            $timestamp = time();
            $filename = 'Export_' . $timestamp . '.xls';
            
            header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
            
            $isPrintHeader = false;

            foreach ($productResult as $row) {

                if (! $isPrintHeader ) {

                    echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
                    $isPrintHeader = true;

                }

                echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";

            }

            exit();

        }````
`````

Comment: Hola bienvenido [es.so]. Es importante para como funciona el sitio, que la respuesta incluya el motivo por el cuál resuelve la duda planteada, ya que además de hacerlo, así se puede aprender. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer].

Comment: Como implemento esta función en mi código, como organizo mis cabeceras, donde pongo mi consulta sql?